# I am getting E: Package 'libgsl0ldbl' has no installation candidate while installing ns3 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

```
kathe@KATHE-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc g++ python python-dev mercurial bzr gdb valgrind gsl-bin libgsl0-dev libgsl0ldbl flex bison tcpdump sqlite sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-dev uncrustify doxygen graphviz imagemagick texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-generic-extra texlive-generic-recommended texinfo dia texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-extra-utils texlive-generic-recommended texi2html python-pygraphviz python-kiwi python-pygoocanvas libgoocanvas-dev python-pygccxml 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgsl-dev' instead of 'libgsl0-dev'
Package libgsl0ldbl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgsl2 libgsl2:i386

E: Package 'libgsl0ldbl' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Where did you get the list of packages you're trying to install?

Comment: It seems like your database is out of date. Running apt-get update (update database) and apt-get upgrade (upgrade packages hopefully fixing dependencies) might me a good first step.

Comment: `sudo apt install libgsl2 `

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgsl) list indicates that `libgsl0ldlbl` was removed in 16.04. At least in my application, `libgsl0-dev` appears to provide the same functionality. `libgsl0-dev` is also at this point a virtual package provided by `libgsl-dev`, so I'm just using the latter at the moment, which seems to work.